# Can anyone tell me 'How to add checkpoints in Jmeter ?'

Tags: jmeter

I want to add checkpoints in my scipts/Recording controller.

Comment: You want to add check points in the starting or in the middle ?
for example If you want to add assertion for each page Suppose you have a page /adminportal/login.jsp you need to add an assertion for this page, right click on the page under threadgroup Assertion>ResponseAssertion>select Test Add and enter the test of the button you need to test, in your case "Button" . i hope this will be enough.

Comment: Please add more information: what have you tried to do? What do you want to test for in your check points? Why doesn't JMeter's online documentation help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Assertions in Apache Jmeter,Jmeter is providing different assertions to verify the samples as required,please read more details with examples here.

https://learn-jmeter.blogspot.in/2016/10/assertions-in-jmeter-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a start point. Very good site I used to get into basic Jmeter:

http://getjmeter.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/assertions-in-jmeter-checkpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the best article I've ever seen. Go through this. You will get a good knowledge.

Here is the link:
http://www.guru99.com/assertions-in-jmeter.html

Comment: Please don't just link websites - if the site changes or goes down your answer becomes useless. Also, if you wrote the article, please say so or you risk your answer being flagged as spam.